# cannot understand a specific type of view in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I am having hard time to understand a specific view in one of the databases I am working on.
Here is the view:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/last_access",
  "language": "query",
  "views": {
    "last_accessed_on": {
      "map": {
        "fields": {
          "indexer.last_accessed_on": "asc"
        },
        "partial_filter_selector": {}
      },
      "reduce": "_count",
      "options": {
        "def": {
          "fields": [
            "indexer.last_access"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usually when I have views I have a function which does the emit in the map part and the in the reduce part it aggregates but the above is way different.
I appreciate if anyone can shed light on the above? what that is? what kind of view is this, which does not have emit?

Answer (score 0):

First clue:

Look at the `language` of the view:

```
  "language": "query",
```

So this isn't a JavaScript view at all. It's the result of building a Mango index with the [/db/_index](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#db-index) endpoint.

As for the reduce, it's using the [built-in reduce functions](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/ddocs.html#built-in-reduce-functions).

Comment: "query" is a native query server enabled by default, it is not present in the configuration file and it is used for index creation.

Comment: @JuanjoRodriguez: I wondered. Can you point to documentation about that? Or if it's not documented, I can add it.

Comment: I didn't find any referencie in de doc. I found it digging into the code (https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/src/couch/src/couch_proc_manager.erl#L112) couch_proc_manager is registering mango_native_proc by default.

Comment: @JuanjoRodriguez: Thanks. I'll work on a doc update.

Answer (score 0):

This document defines an index that can be used for accelerating [Mango Queries](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#api-db-find) evaluation.

In your case, you are defining an index over the "indexer.last_accessed_on" attribute of every document in your database. It is like emiting this attribute for every document in your database (Only documents with the attribute will be present in the index). You can check index creation syntax [here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/api/database/find.html#db-index).

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain how the view is defined, which is what the question is about.

Comment: Thanks so when I have the option of using map/reduce why should I use this format?

Comment: I am trying to understand when to use this format and when I should apply map reduce?